# Using Net::HTTP.get for an https url

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use `Net::HTTP.get()` for an https URL:

```
@data = Net::HTTP.get(uri, Net::HTTP.https_default_port())
```

However, I get the following result when I try to print the results:

> can't convert URI::HTTPS into String

What's the deal? I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 (OS X)

Comment: Just an FYI, we were connecting to a 3rd party server temporarily that had certificate issues so we had to use `IO.copy_stream( open( url, { ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } ), download_path )` to just disable the SSL verification. In our case, security wasn't an issue, the server was out of our control and it was a temporary solution.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Original answer:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://example.com/some/path")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
@data = http.get(uri.request_uri)
```

As pointed out in the comments, this is more elegant:

```
require "open-uri"
@data = URI.parse("https://example.com/some/path").read
```

Comment: I'll give this as the answer because it's the answer to what I asked, but the real answer is to point out i'm approaching this the wrong way. Use `URI.parse(uri_string).read` instead, works so, so beautifully.

Comment: hatorade, I can't get that with ".read" to work for me at all. could you post a full answer to your own question with how you do this?

Comment: What does `VERIFY_NONE` imply? What should possibly be done instead?

Comment: that's a flag that means the veracity of the certificate is ignored, but this was a while ago so I'm not sure why you need to set it.

Comment: shouldn't it be @data = http.get uri.request_uri ??

Comment: @frabcus, you need to `require 'open-uri'` for the .read to work.

Comment: Not working for me on Ruby 2.0. Any tips? I get "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Pathname into String"

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's question to imply that SSL verification isn't desired, so why are you suggesting VERIFY_NONE?

Comment: Do note that setting `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` will disable certificate verification. An attacker might be able to pretend to be the server you are connecting. In other words, apart from encryption, you are not getting much benefit from SSL at all.

Comment: This approach doesn’t seem to capture the body with error message in the case of status code 400s.

Answer (score 39):

EDIT: My approach works, but @jason-yeo's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36543895/2317829) is far easier.

It appears as of 2.1.2 <s>the preferred</s> a documented method is as follows (directly quoting [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS)):

> HTTPS is enabled for an HTTP connection by #use_ssl=.
>
> ```
> uri = URI('https://secure.example.com/some_path?query=string')
>
> Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,   
>   :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
>   request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
>
>   response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object 
> end
> ```
>
> In previous versions of Ruby you would need to require ‘net/https’ to use
>   HTTPS. This is no longer true.

Comment: This is not true. As of Ruby 2.0.0, `Net::HTTP.get` is sufficient to do a HTTPS get request if the URI object is passed a `https` url. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36543895/382740.

Answer (score 28):

In Ruby 2.0.0 and above, simply passing in an uri object with a `https` url is sufficient to do a HTTPS get request.

```
uri = URI('https://encrypted.google.com')
Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

You may verify this by performing a get request on a [domain](https://expired.badssl.com/) with an expired certificate.

```
uri = URI('https://expired.badssl.com/')
Net::HTTP.get(uri)
# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

It was introduced by this [commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/708d76a3b1ab9d5b888a9e68773406e289860aa0#diff-8c2ab8e0fb4f052e1d95ab6334e192c1) in Ruby 2.0.0.

The `get_response` method, which is called by the `Net::HTTP.get` method, [sets](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/778bbac8ac2ae50f0987c4888f7158296ee5bbdd/lib/net/http.rb#L481) `:use_ssl` to true when the `uri.scheme` is "https".

Disclaimer: I understand that the question is for Ruby 1.8.7, but since this is one of the top few search results when one searches for "https ruby", I've decided to answer anyway.

Comment: As a data point, I have found this to not be true in ruby 2.2.10 . It did open the connection on port 443, but did not use SSL. Of course, the foreign server would have nothing to do with it, and closed the connection without a reply, leading to much teeth gnashing on my end. I had to call `http.use_ssl = true` to force it to actually use ssl, and then things went swimmingly.

Answer (score 4):

this should look as:

```
uri.port = Net::HTTP.https_default_port()
@data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

Comment: that worked, but now the external API is complaining that I sent a plain HTTP request to an HTTPS port...

Comment: haha, right ;) see below solution Stef provided, it should work

Comment: it doesn't, i get an error saying "undefined method `use_ssl='"

Comment: try to also require 'net/https'