# Stubing HTTPS call using WebMock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, webmock

I'd like to stub `https` call using `webmock`.
Let's assume gateway url as `https://some_gateway.com`.

After doing:

```
stub_request(:post, 'https://some_gateway.com').with(body: {})
```

in specs.

I use Net::HTTP to generate request:

```
 Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('https://some_gateway.com'), {})
```

I receive problem because Webmock expects `https://some_gateway.com` but receives version with added port 433 so: `http://www.secure.fake-payment.com:443/gateway_prod` so can't see registered stub.

How can I deal with this behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the answer for this question: [WebMock: Rspec - Test Facebook Validation by using JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760255/webmock-rspec-test-facebook-validation-by-using-json-response)

Your code will do  `http` request with port 443 vs doing really `https`

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('https://some_gateway.com'), {})
```

And here you can find the answer how to do `https` request using Net::HTTP
[Using Net::HTTP.get for an https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786779/using-nethttp-get-for-an-https-url)