# Get image using imgur API in Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imgur

I'm trying to pull an image from imgur using the provided API with Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0. I've tried constructing an http request in various ways as listed in the Ruby 2.0.0 docs to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
def imgur
  headers    = {
    "Authorization" => "Client-ID " + my_client_id
  }
  path       = "/3/gallery/image/#{img_id}.json"
  uri = URI("https://api.imgur.com"+path)
  request, data = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path, headers)

  response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start {|http| http.request(request) }
  puts "response:"
  p response
  puts response
end
```

where `img_id` and `my_client_id` are just hardcoded with appropriate values. (`imgur` method is called within a controller action corresponding to my site's root url)

This is the response I get back when I run `rails s` (so I'm using localhost:3000) and then visit the root url, localhost:3000 (which does call the action that calls `imgur`):

```
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x007f8a6ce0da78>
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, this worked:

`curl --header "Authorization: Client-ID my_client_id" https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/image/7x98w9T.json`

(again, `my_client_id` is hardcoded with my actual client ID). Now to get it to work on Ruby...

Anyone know the right way to do this?

Comment: if you use curl or wget with those parameters does it work?

Comment: this worked: $ curl --header "Authorization: Client-ID XXXXXXXXX" https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/7x98w9T.json where the X's are my client ID... the imgur image id is one for an image i picked at random

Comment: in the comment above I meant to type api.imgur.com/3/gallery/image/7x98w9T.json (though I tested what I actually wrote in the above comment and it also works...)

Comment: Maybe because it's `https`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786779/using-nethttp-get-for-an-https-url

Comment: @VladtheImpala, it was https! I thought giving the uri a string starting with https would do the trick but it did not actually use SSL. Got it to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable https to make an https call.

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

I know this was figured out, but I figured I'd add an explicit answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @VladtheImpala pointed out, the issue is with SSL. Though I included `https` in the URI string, the HTTP request was not in fact using SSL. Here's the code where I explicitly set the HTTP request to use SSL:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

def imgur    
  puts "Let's get some pics"

  headers    = {
    "Authorization" => "Client-ID my_client_id"
  }

  #http       = Net::HTTP.new("https://api.imgur.com")
  path       = "/3/gallery/image/7x98w9T.json"
  uri = URI.parse("https://api.imgur.com"+path)
  request, data = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path, headers)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  response = http.request(request)
  puts response.body
end
```

Works like a charm ;)