# Saving information from form and making api get request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, get

I'm trying to have a user input info via a form, then make an api get request based on that information (in rails). How should I go about doing this? Specifically what js/ruby methods should I use, should I put the api request in a controller or view? I'm really stuck and would love any direction.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a very good question for Stack Overflow. Perhaps you should try http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use Net::HTTP ruby class for this in you controller. Please check

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786863/3815905

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `simple_form` gem to do that. Please find the step by step tutorial and sample project [here](http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/documentation)