# Net::HTTP.get fails with HTTPS with Headers

Tags: ruby

Ruby v2 introduced `Net:HTTP.get(uri)` which allowed for handling HTTPS URI objects seamlessly.

For example, you can call `Net:HTTP.get(URI('https://google.com'))` without any special incantations.

However, the minute I supply any headers as a second argument. I get a type error.

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.get(URI('https://google.com'), { 'Accept': 'text/html' }) 
# => Caused by TypeError: no implicit conversion of URI::HTTPS into String
```

Is there any workaround that doesn't require using the older methods?

Comment: Example from docs: `Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://www.example.com/index.html'), { 'Accept' => 'text/html' })` - notice that headers are separate argument from uri

Comment: You didn't read my question carefully. I give an example using that same syntax as an example, and it doesn't work for HTTPS.

Comment: In your example you are passing only one argument to the `get` method: `URI('https://google.com', { 'Accept': 'text/html' })`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Net::HTTP.get for an https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786779/using-nethttp-get-for-an-https-url)

Comment: That's a typo. Updated. Just copy and paste `require 'net/http'; Net::HTTP.get(URI('https://google.com'), { 'Accept': 'text/html' })` into IRB, you'll get the error.

Comment: _which allowed for handling HTTPS URI objects seamlessly_ - can you point to the documentation which says that?

Comment: See the source code: https://github.com/ruby/net-http/blob/f3e65e2a313203ff53302dd2feb1cda712e2a24b/lib/net/http.rb#L485

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had this same issue. My problem was that my ruby version (2.7) does not  support passing headers to `Net::HTTP.get`.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#get-method

The headers support has been included in ruby 3

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#get-method